# Gnuplot pm3d plotting from file

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having a problem with pm3d. I have data in the format `x y # # # #`, and I want to add the four #'s and plot their sum versus x,y with something like this:

```
set pm3d map
splot 'data' 1:2:($3 + $4 + $5+ $6)
```

I've made sure that my data has lines wherever the first number changes, but I'm getting the  error:

> ';' expected

after `data`. If I get rid of everything after `data` then gnuplot is able to plot, but of course the plot is not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the keyword `using`.

```
splot 'data' using 1:2:($3+$4+$5+$6)
```

I suppose it's an easy one to miss because in the examples it is often abbreviated `u`:

```
splot 'data' u 1:2:...
```

Comment: @alexvas -- No problem.  We all make those errors (and then spend hours ripping our hair out because of them).